# Custom feature not visible in sharepoint

Tags: 2010

i have a custom site level feature in sharepoint 2010 which creates and a timer job.
However after deploying ".wsp" i am not abe to see the feature on site or farm level.

But i am able to activate the feature via stsadm.

why is this can be enabled via stsadm but not showing in feature list ?

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="EDKERROKFeature" Description="some desc" Id="85706687-4456-4ec2-9324-5b0810adea20" ReceiverAssembly="EDKERROK, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=939ee9b4e9b91d4f" ReceiverClass="EDKERROK.Features.Feature1.Feature1EventReceiver" Scope="Site"></Feature>
```

Comment: check that the feature is not hidden.

Comment: Check for hidden features using the following command: Get-SPFeature -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.Hidden -eq $true -and $_.Scope -eq “WEB”} | Sort-Object DisplayName | Select DisplayName, Id

Answer (score 1):

Run the command to find hidden features as suggested previously. If that doesn't help, run SharePoint 2010 Management Shell from one of the SharePoint servers and type:

> Install-SPFeature -ScanForFeatures

This will show you any features that are available in SharePoint but have not been installed. You can install any missing features using the command:

> Install-SPFeature -AllExistingFeatures

See the following TechNet Article for more information:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607825(v=office.14).aspx